# Customized Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-science

Is there a way to customize jupyter notebooks in pdf format ?

I understand using : jupyter nbconvert
_file=./revtex_nocode.tplx myfile.ipynb , and revtex_nocode contains the customizing code.

However is there any standard file available for the same ? if not can some one help me with basic customization in it ?

Comment: what kind of customization you want?

Comment: something like the explanation markdowns are to the left and graphs are to the right.

Comment: I do not have the idea of how to do it, but it seems not to be that straight forward task also.

Comment: There are some basic templates from page no. 39 of this [pdf](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/nbconvert/latest/nbconvert.pdf)